# Non-chargeable event participants

Tags: civievent, participants

I have a some event roles (tutor and administrator) that are not chargeable. I want to be able to add these from the back end - Register Event Participants, but I have to accept a fee and provide charging information which is not wanted. I've set the roles to be "not counted" but that doesn't help. If I add a zero fee then that is going to show as an option for the online booking. In [How do I configure a free event ticket option for internal use without it showing up on the website?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/how-do-i-configure-a-free-event-ticket-option-for-internal-use-without-it-showin/13190#13190) there are two suggestions: I can't go down the price set for these existing events and the other option suggests that you can have a role that isn't charged.

Am I missing something?

I might be able to do it by importing participants but that's more work than it should be. as I'd have to export event and contact data and then create a spreadsheet.

Comment: odd. i would have thought this was simpler too but checking on dmaster i don't see a quick solution that does not involve price sets and/or cividiscount both of which may still cause something to show publicly that is unwanted

Comment: have you considered doing this via the CMS UI as a posed to directly into CiviCRM - for example via webform or via caldera. This maybe a workaround to what you want to do. You also have the option of using discount codes and giving Tutors/Admins a 100% discount to have a zero fee. Finally we have a event role based pricing extension we wrote a few years back you may try - haven't tried it in a while but maybe of use. https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.rolebasedpricing

Comment: @ParvezSaleh thanks for all the work around suggestions, but they are are all learning and effort for something which I think should be possible in the manual add participant. Certainly that's how I would normally want to do it as the individuals need to be added. In this particular case as I was doing this post-event for the historical event, the export events and people, match them manually and then import participants proved to be very quick (probably quicker and more reliable than all the manual inputs.

Comment: Ok cool, understand that its not always straight forward and understanding that its a bulk process helps - the export import route is quickest in that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using price sets for the ones that are public and chargeable? If so, we add an option and set the visibility to Admin. Then we can add them in the back-end, but they don't show up publicly.